# What are the differece between core/email_template and core/email_template_mailer

Tags: magento-1.7, email, email-templates

every one ,can anyone tell me please what are the difference between `core/email_template_mailer` and `core/email_template`...I want to know its each function in details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One big difference is `setReplyTo()`
*(My Magento version is 1.7.0.1)*

I added `setReplyTo()` functionality to the `email_template_mailer` via a customization of a core file:
<kbd>app/code/local/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Mailer.php</kbd>
Why? Because it was easier to add a couple lines of code than to rewrite the code utilizing `email_template_mailer` to send Admin copies of order emails. I wanted the emails to come showing the customers' name and having their email as Reply-To.
*Note that changing the From Email to their email gets you blacklisted, so I change the From Name and for the From Email use my own auto-confirm@ address.*

While reviewing the two files:
<kbd>app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php</kbd>
and
<kbd>app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Mailer.php</kbd>
I concluded that `email_template_mailer` is a simplified wrapper for `email_template`, probably a result of how difficult it used to be to just send an email.

The core file <kbd>app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Mailer.php</kbd> uses `email_template`:
*line 64:*           `$emailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template');`
and then goes on to use `sendTransactional()` just like sending email had always been.

<kbd>app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php</kbd> defines the method `sendTransactional()` as well as instantiates a private Zend_Mail member object:
*line 141:*           `$this->_mail = new Zend_Mail('utf-8');`

`sendTransactional()` is a wrapper for the public method `send()`, which does the heavy lifting building the email for `Zend_Mail`. The `send()` function populates out the various headers and prepares the body's plain text or HTML content with `$this->getProcessedTemplate($variables, true);`. And then this `send()` calls `Zend_Mail`'s own `send()`.

The big deal here is that Varien made the `email_template` to minimize the need for directly editing code by translating the templates and variables in the database into useful emails.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is quite vague. Take a look at:

- `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php`, and
- `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Mailer.php`

Magento refers to them as

> Template model

And

> Email Template Mailer Model

Respectively.

The `Mailer.php` model is responsible for the email functionality, i.e setting templates, setting senders & sending the actual email.

The `Template.php` model is responsible for configuration of the actual email template.

All relevant functions can be found within the aforementioned model files.